# Thunderbird gFolderTreeView documentation?

Tags: thunderbird-addon

I'm struggling to learn how Thunderbird extension works but I'm stuck by the lack of documentation.
Inside an extension I found:

```
gFolderTreeView._modeNames...
...
gFolderTreeView.getFolderTreeMode(viewName);
```

Google gives no help in trying to understand something more about **gFolderTreeView**. I can only find examples where it is used but no API description. Where can I find the list of its methods, properties and a description of what they do ?

Answer (score 2):

The only way I know would be to take a closer look at the Thunderbird source code.

`gFolderTreeView` is defined at https://dxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/source/mail/base/content/folderPane.js#129. The `nsITreeView` interface, which seems to be one of the thinks `gFolderTreeView` implements, is defined in https://dxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/source/mozilla/layout/xul/tree/nsITreeView.idl.

I found it by searching at https://dxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/ for `id:gFolderTreeView` and `file:nsITreeView`

Note that the links are to the latest sources. If you need to look at the sources for older Thunderbird versions, you need to switch the tree from [`comm-central`](https://dxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/source/) to e.g. [`comm-esr45`](https://dxr.mozilla.org/comm-esr45/source/).
The Code that is used by both Thunderbird and Firefox is in the [`mozilla-central`](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/) tree